# Info.plist file not updating location

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am attempting to reorganize my files in my Xcode project. Moving the Info.plist file went fine the first time - I was able to create a new group called "Supporting Files" and move it into there. To do this, I went to the file inspector (of Info.plist) on the right-hand side of the screen and changed the "Location" dropdown to "Relative to Project." This generated the new path "Source/Supporting Files/Info.plist"

Great, so I copied that path, headed to the project's build settings, and pasted the path of the Info.plist in the Packaging>Info.plist File section. Unfortunately, I made a mistake when naming the new group "Supporting Files." To keep up with common naming conventions, I would have liked the file to read "SupportingFiles" without a space. So, I renamed the folder to "SupportingFiles" and the path of Info.plist in the file inspector pane did not update. It still read "Supporting Files" (see image below)
[image: Info.plist file inspector]

I tried updating the path in the build settings, but Xcode still cannot find the Info.plist file and says: "Build input file cannot be found: <path/to/Info.plist>"

In an attempt to start over, I moved the Info.plist file out of the group and back where it originally was - "Source/Info.plist" and deleted the"SupportingFiles" group (probably a mistake).

Again, changing the file's location in Build Settings>Packaging>Info.plist to "Source/Info.plist" did not work as the locaiton in the file inspector has not changed from the image above. I also don't know if there is still a reference to a group named "SupportingFiles" somewhere because when I try to add a new group and title it "SupportingFiles" Xcode throws an error: "Could not rename “New Group” to “SupportingFiles”."

Furthermore, if I add the "Supporting Files" group back to the project and change the location in Build Setting>Packaging>Info.plist, it still does not work. Thank you in advance for helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some digging around in project's local files on my computer, it is evident that there is still a reference to the old folder "SupportingFiles" (see image below) despite deleting the folder in Xcode.
[image: file image]

Moving the Info.plist file back into "Supporting Files" and deleting "SupportingFiles" in Finder then allowed me to add a new group called "SupportingFiles" directly within Xcode. I then moved the Info.plist file into "SupportingFiles" from "Supporting Files" and the location updated in the file inspector. Then, I headed back to Build Settings>Packaging>Info.plist, and changed the file path to "Source/SupportingFiles/Info.plist" and Xcode was able to find the Info.plist file.